# Востановление файла dbf?

Tags: dbf

Мы используем VFP 7. Когда пытаемся открыть один из DBF файлов - получаем ошибку "Доступ к файлу запрещен" Никто не использует файл DBF. Если мы сделаем копию файла и сохраним его в другом месте, то он работает. Мы пробовали переименовать файл, но он не работает. Почему это так, и как восстановить доступ к файлу?

Comment: Даже не знаю: подсказка, да ещё на русском, изменение расположения файла и его доступность.... Одно точно - это не зависит от прав доступа к файлу, точно нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если повреждено достаточно много данных - вообще беда. Чем поврежден файл? Вот - здесь статья с описанием, она поможет вам https://toster.ru/q/183103

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).